# Efficient way to build a key using two strings in java?

Tags: java

Below is the code I have written to build a key using two strings.  If either of them is null, empty or blank use the other string to build the key.  However if both of them does not qualify, return an empty string. I would like to write a better and efficient piece of code.  Here is my sample code

```
if (!StringAssistant.isBlank(string1) && !StringAssistant.isBlank(string2)) {
    return StringAssistant.append(string1, string2);
}
if (StringAssistant.isBlank(string1) && !StringAssistant.isBlank(string2)) {
    return string2;
}
if (!StringAssistant.isBlank(string1) && StringAssistant.isBlank(string2)) {
    return string1;
}
return "";
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What error are u getting?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another Stack Exchange site:  codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something as "simple" as :

```
return StringAssistant.append(StringAssistant.isBlank(string1)?"":string1,StringAssistant.isBlank(string2)?"":string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply append the two string and return the value

```
return string1+string2;
```

or if you want to use your `StringAssistant.append`

```
return return StringAssistant.append(string1, string2);
```

Notice that the empty string doesn't has an impact on the return value. So if you append the string and return it will result the same.

If the string can be null then you need to handle the `null` value separately. if either string is null then you can return an empty string. You can handle it in your append method.

Comment: In other words ignore the "ignore blank strings" requirements? Do think it is useful to ignore requirements?

Comment: oh , i missed the null string part..

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the code as shown below, I suggest you evaluate the `isBlank` for the both the strings first (so that for large strings you would get the results quicker):

```
boolean string1Blank = !StringAssistant.isBlank(string1);
boolean string2Blank = !StringAssistant.isBlank(string2);

if(string1Blank && string2Blank) {
     return StringAssistant.append(string1, string2);
} else if(string1Blank) {
    return string2;
} else if(string2Blank) {
     return string1;
} else {
    return "";
}
```